# How to create a time lapse map with Tableau

Tags: geolocation, tableau-api

I created a map of geolocated tweets in a tableau map. I am trying now to crate, inside this map a time lapse according when these tweets were tweeted for a presentation, but I cannot find the way. Actually I don't know if that is possible with tableau.

I attach a capture of how the maps looks right now with all the tweets.

[map with tweets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByHve.png)

Comment: You should be able to do it with the Pages shelf. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/buildmanual_shelves_pages.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dataset which is not updated on a regular basis with new dates, then I might have an idea:

- right-click on [created_at] and create a parameter based on that dimension
  [image: configuration of my slider]
- right-click this parameter and "Show Parameter"
- change the appereance of the parameter-card to "Slider"
- then create a calculated variable to get a filter on the date, something like this:

  ```
  IF [Date Parameter] = [created_at] THEN "show"
  ELSE "hide"
  END
  ```
- with this filter on "show" you can only see the tweets of that exact day

---

**Here is my result with an exemplary dataset.**

(It should work the same way on maps.)

[image: my result]

Comment: with a bit more adjustments to the parameter and the filter-variable you might also achieve something like showing whole weeks or months instead of only exact days. ;-) but this i haven't tested yet.